# Is it okay to use DataStax's fork of open-source Cassandra on GitHub?

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra's release cycle is quite slow. From the user's point of view, there is a desire to quickly introduce and use more innovative features.

If you look at Github Datastax cassandra, the latest features such as SAI and UCS are already reflected.
https://github.com/datastax/cassandra

If it is a quality applicable to production, I would like to try it.
tell me your opinions.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually no releases from that fork yet because it is still being worked on which means that it is not ready for production use.

At best, consider it as the equivalent of "nightly builds" which are not stable enough even for development purposes. Also, it comes with no support yet so I wouldn't use it.

It is a work-in-progress and there is no estimate for when it is available for general availability. For the record, the information I posted here is correct as of March 2023. Cheers!